# PyCharm: How to make commit+push the default?

Tags: pycharm

I am very lazy and I would like to always push my commit immediately.

Is there a way to make commit+push the default? I would like to use as little keystrokes as possible.

Comment: I created an issue for this feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the answer to your question (based on PhpStorm):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002172100-Set-Commit-and-Push-as-default-button

> Unfortunately, there is no option to change the default behavior for the button.
>
> However, you may want to disable buttons grouping via "Settings - Appearance & Behavior - Appearance | Window options -> Allow merging buttons on dialogs."
>
> In this case, you will have a separate button for "Commit and Push".
>
> As an option, you could use a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+K on Windows).

on MacOS the keyboard shortcut is Shift+Command+K (symbols: ⇧ + ⌘ + K, see this [page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) for an explanation about MacOS shortcut commands).

I hope this can help (PyCharm Professional 2019.3).

[image: PyCharm Professional 2019.3, settings]

---

Some news...

> Starting 2020.3 Commit and Commit & Push buttons are both visible now

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002172100/comments/360002372420

[image: PyCharm 2020.3]

Answer (score 2):

As [Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60554223/13020974) pointed out, there is no way to make commit+push the default.

However, you can use a keybind for commit+push: `Ctrl + Alt + K`

Answer (score 1):

**Why not use Bash-profile to do it for you?**
Thats what I do. I have automated most of my git commands with aliases and functions to automate processes such as updating my forked repo, navigating to different project folders etc.

The best option for you, given that it is not inherently supported on PyCharm, you can edit your bash-profile and simply add this function (feel free to name it as you wish):

```
function <name>() {

    # To add all the files (if you want)
    git add . 

    # Supply a message to be sent in the commit
    git commit -a -m "$1"

    git push
}
```

**Note:**

- Pass the commit message in this function
- If you don't want to add all files (by default), remove `git add .`
- If you want to be specific in your **push** command, you can supply additional arguments for upstream/branch etc as additional parameters and you can access them in your function with $2, $3 .... and so on.
- After you add this function in your bash profile, please restart your terminal or run this : `source ~/.bash_profile'`    (of course you've to make sure the path to the bash-profile is right)

With this, in your PyCharm, when you run this function in terminal (with arguments supplied), it will handle all the git functions mentioned inside. You can chill and see the stuff running on the screen.

I hope this achieves what you want.

Comment: I used the command-line from 1996-2020. Don't want to use it anymore. I want a nice UX.